# How to check date in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have date variable in freemarker. i want to check that date is today or yesterday. If that date is today then need to display `Today` otherwise display `Yesterday`.  Please can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that these are only possibilities (today and yesterday), then you could define a function like:

```
<#function isToday(aDate)>
  <#return .now?date?iso_local == aDate?date?iso_local>
</#function>
```

and then you can use it for example as

```
${isToday(theDate)?string("today", "yesterday")}
```

Note that you will need FreeMarker 2.3.17 or later for that function to work. Also be careful with the Server time-zone, as that's what it uses in this example (unless you set that in the FreeMarker configuration manually... or with `#setting` in the templates).